# MongoDB Finding All Documents from Query and Adding Field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to figure out the best command line to find all of the documents within my collection that match my query parameters and then add a field `"descriptions_id":"navy-blue"` to each of those documents. Basically I just created a collection called `descriptions` that I now want to reference in all of my documents in my collection `images`. I'm using `db.images.find( { color: "navy-blue" })` which pulls all of my documents correctly, but now I want to update those documents and add in `descriptions_id: "navy-blue"`. Do I run an `update` command to add this field to all of those documentations? It doesn't seem like from the documentation that this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) command takes a query object to identify which documents to update.  Include the `{multi: true}` option to apply the update to *all* matched docs instead of just the first one.

```js
db.images.update(
    {color: "navy-blue"}, 
    {$set: {descriptions_id: "navy-blue"}},
    {multi: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [bulk find and update](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) operations. It will be beneficial if you want to update large number of documents. The query will be like following:

```
var bulk = db.images.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { color: "navy-blue" } ).update( {$set: {descriptions_id: "navy-blue"}});
bulk.execute();
```